# How to inherit two parent object to a child object, but the argument of the 2nd inherited object is the 1st inherited object

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, arguments

In Javascript, I was searching for how to inherit an object when constructor has arguments. And i found the answer for this question.

Now I need to inherit two parent object to a child object, but the argument of the 2nd inherited object is the first inherited object. How to do this?

In the difficult way:

```
function ChildObj() { 
    this.Parent1 = new ParentObj1 ( arguments ); 
    this.Parent2 = new ParentObj2 ( this.Parent1);
}
```

But how to do it in this way:

```
function ChildObj() { 
   Parent1Obj.call ( this, arguments ) ;
   Parent2Obj.call( this, <<-- how to indicate Parent1Obj as argument -->> ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please notice at first that in JavaScript's prototypical way of inheritance you can't inherit from two different prototype objects. Of course this was not asked in your question, yet assuming `ChildObj`s inherit from `Parent1.prototype`, you can't use *and don't need* `Parent2.prototype` any more. That means you might want to restructure `Parent2` from a constructor to a normal function that adds methods to objects - called **Mixin pattern**.

> How to tell `Parent2` that it is invoked on a `Parent1` object?

You don't need to pass that explicitly as an argument. Using duck typing, the current instance (`this`) can be known to be a `Parent1` object as it already got it's methods and other properties from `Parent1Obj.call(this, arguments)`. Assuming you have set up the prototype chain correctly, the object on which `Parent2` is applied also is `instanceof Parent1`.

Of course you also could just pass the `Parent1` constructor function as an additional argument next to `this`. However, I'm not sure whether the behavior of the mixin things should depend on the [super] constructor of the passed object. It might be better to pass some more descriptive options, and let the `ChildObj` constructor choose what the right ones are instead of the `Parent2` function.